# Catel freezing on usercontrol focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, catel

I got a simple application with nested usercontrol.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0">Test TextBox</TextBox>

    <userControls:SuggestUserControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
        DataContext="{Binding CitizenshipViewModel}" />        
</Grid>
```

Violation of the naming convention is reason for subsequent re-use of this usercontrol. In that case I'm registering custom view model in App.xaml.cs:

```
var viewLocator = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IViewModelLocator>();
viewLocator.Register(typeof(SuggestUserControl), typeof(CitizenshipSuggestViewModel));
```

CitizenshipSuggestViewModel is a simple class with empty constructor, some additional logic (which I commented in test reason) and derived from base class SuggestModule:

```
    public class SuggestModule<TEntity> : ViewModelBase 
        where TEntity : class, ISuggestable, new()
    {
        #region Private fields

        private readonly IDataBaseService _dataBaseService;

        #endregion


        #region Default constructor

        public SuggestModule(IDataBaseService dataBaseService)
        {
            Argument.IsNotNull(() => dataBaseService);
            _dataBaseService = dataBaseService;

            //Loading data from context
            var collection = _dataBaseService.LoadObservableCollectionOf<TEntity>();
            ItemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<TEntity>(collection);
            ItemsCollection.Sort();
        }

        #endregion

        ...Some logic here...
   }
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            public MainWindowViewModel(Person person)
            {
                Argument.IsNotNull(()=>person);

                Person = person;
            }
    
            [Model]
            public Person Person
            {
                get => GetValue<Person>(PersonProperty);
                set => SetValue(PersonProperty, value);
            }

            public static readonly PropertyData PersonProperty = 
                RegisterProperty<MainWindowViewModel, Person>(model => model.Person);

            [ViewModelToModel("Person")]
            public Citizenship Citizenship
            {
                get => GetValue<Citizenship>(CitizenshipProperty);
                set => SetValue(CitizenshipProperty, value);
            }

            public static readonly PropertyData CitizenshipProperty = 
                RegisterProperty<MainWindowViewModel, Citizenship>(model => model.Citizenship);

            public Citizenship Citizenship
            {
                get => GetValue<Citizenship>(CitizenshipProperty);
                set => SetValue(CitizenshipProperty, value);
            }
    
            public static readonly PropertyData CitizenshipProperty =
                RegisterProperty<MainWindowViewModel, Citizenship>(model => model.Citizenship);
    
            public IViewModel CitizenshipViewModel
            {
                get => GetValue<IViewModel>(CitizenshipViewModelProperty);
                set => SetValue(CitizenshipViewModelProperty, value);
            }
    
            public static readonly PropertyData CitizenshipViewModelProperty = 
                RegisterProperty<MainWindowViewModel, IViewModel>(model => model.CitizenshipViewModel);
    
            protected override async Task InitializeAsync()
            {
                await base.InitializeAsync();
    
                CitizenshipViewModel = this.GetTypeFactory().CreateInstance<CitizenshipSuggestViewModel>();
            }    
        }
    }
```

So, when application fully loaded, particularly ItemsCollection on SuggestModule is already filled with data from context, in Log got this information:

```
12:19:34:844 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.Views.ViewToViewModelMappingHelper] [1] Initializing view model container to manage ViewToViewModel mappings
12:19:34:864 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.Views.ViewToViewModelMappingHelper] [1] Initializing view model 'CitizenshipSuggestViewModel'
12:19:34:874 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.Views.ViewToViewModelMappingHelper] [1] Initialized view model 'CitizenshipSuggestViewModel'
12:19:34:895 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.Views.ViewToViewModelMappingHelper] [1] Initialized view model container to manage ViewToViewModel mappings
```

But now, if I getting focus on second TextBox, which is part of nested usercontrol I have about 5...6 seconds freeze. Logging information in this time:

```
12:23:21:212 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:21:387 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:21:809 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:21:901 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:22:016 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:22:063 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:22:221 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:22:235 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:22:585 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:22:654 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:22:703 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:23:019 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:23:319 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:23:431 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:24:105 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:24:566 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:24:644 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:25:803 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
12:23:26:115 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [1] Cleared type constructor cache
```

How can I avoid this behavior?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using InitializeAsync instead of the constructor for data retrieval
- Using Orc.EntityFramework6 instead of obsolete Catel.Extensions.EntityFramework6

Are solved my problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

1. We recommend to use InitializeAsync instead of the constructor for data retrieval
2. Are you using Catel 5.2 in combination with VS 2017? Does the issue still occur when you run without a debugger attached?

Comment: Yes, 5.2 Catel, VS2017, and without debbuger is the same behavior…

Comment: Can you create a repro & ticket on GitHub? Then we'll look into it!